# No anda PHP dentro de CSS si la variable no es directa

Tags: php, css

queria consutlar porque al querer leer la variables de php en el css, si le pongo un valor a mano lo toma perfecto pero si este mismo valor lo traigo de una variable sacado de una tabla, no lo toma.
hago un var_dump de la variable y está con el valor perfecto e igual al que escribo (red)

en el archivo css tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');         
$color = $color_del_usuario;
?>

.tabla_titulo {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0.50em;
            background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;
        }
```

De esa forma no me anda, pero si ahora le pongo lo siguiente si anda perfecto

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');         
$color = "red";
?>

.tabla_titulo {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0.50em;
            background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;
        }
```

Que es lo que está mal ? No entiendo porque no funciona
Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería

**Actualizacion !**
Paso un ejemplo de codigo de los dos archivos que hice para probar

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        if(!empty($_POST['colores']))
               {
               $quecolor=$_POST['colores'];
               }
        ?>
        <title>Probando</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.php" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabla">Esta tabla tendria que tenes un fondo de color <?php echo $quecolor; ?></div>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label> Cambiar el color de la tabla</label>
            <input type="text" name="colores">
            <button name="submit" >cambiar color</button>
        </form>
</html>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php 

$quecolor=$_POST['colores'];
               
header('Content-type: text/css');

?>
#tabla {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3em;
        background-color: <?php echo $quecolor; ?>;
}
```

Eso pasa una variable de formulario con el color para que lo toma el CSS. El problema es que la variable, si bien se llena bien, cuando la lee el css si uno se fija en el inspector de código, da un  error
"**Notice: Undefined index: colores in main.php on line 4**"

Y despues sigue el codigo y ya no trae el valor de variable. No entiendo como definirla si ya está definida en el index.

Comment: ¿Y cuando imprimes la variable $color_del_usuario que retorna?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Retorna RED

Comment: Ese dato viene se una consulta a la base de datos  he probado de todo. Guardarla en una variable de sesión, en una común y nada. Ya no se que más puede ser

Comment: Que te imprime $color en el primer script? un campo vacio?

Comment: Así es. Cuando veo la página generada con el inspector de Chrome en el background-color: queda así sin el texto del color que debería tener.

Comment: Entiendo que este script lo estas incluyendo desde otro script que es el que asigna el valor `red` a la variable `$color_del_usuario`, ¿cierto?  ¿Y has verificado que la variable `$color_del_usuario` llegue correctamente a este script haciendo un `echo $color_del_usuario` antes de asignarlo a `$color`?  Quizás tienes un problema de ámbito de variables o quizás estas invocando este script **antes** de definir `$color_del_usuario`. Y quizás te parece que sí tiene ese valor `red` porque lo imprimes desde el otro script, pero no este mismo.

Comment: Buenas. Si la variable se llena por una consulta a la base de datos . La misma se hace previo a <HEAD>  por lo que cuando llamo al archivo de estilo ya esta cargada. Hasta he probado de meterlo en una variable de session para tenerlo disponible todo el tiempo y nada. No hay forma de que lo imprima ahí si viene de una variable. Ya no se que hacer

Comment: Bueno, eso es lo que te parece, pero no es lo que ocurre. Es decir, ¿has hecho lo que te he pedido con lo del `echo $color_del_usuario` justo una linea antes de asignarlo a `$color`?  Quizas la estas asignando dentro de una función, por lo tanto esa variable $color no seria global y no saldria de la propia función a menos que la retornaras con un return o la definieras como global antes y dentro de la función.  Vamos un poco a ciegas, la verdad, creo que falta contexto.

Comment: dejo en el comentario de abajo el código de dos archivos de ejemplo ya que en respuesta rapida no me deja por cantidad de caracteres. Si se prueban esos dos archivos, se ve que no carga el color de fondo. Pero si en el mail.php le ponemos la linea " $quecolor="red"; " por ejemplo, si lo pone rojo el dondo. Al parecer es un tema con declarar la variable en el mail.php pero no se como hacer eso sin perder el contenido

Comment: OK ahí lo borre, perdón no sabia.

En el ejemplo que envio lo hice así para pasarlo por para no pasar estructura de tabla y demas. Yo el dato no es que lo traigo de un formulario, sino que lo traigo de una consulta a una base de datos como decia anteiormente.
Esa consutla a la baes si la coloco en el archivo main.php la hace y llena las variables, ya que he probado de ponerlo en una variable de session y luego la leo de otro lugar del sitio y me trae el valor. Pero en el mismo archivo mail.php la deja vacia en la parte donde la llamo sobre el background :-(

Comment: ¿El archivo que tu dices `mail.php` seria el `index.php` de tu pregunta? ¿O haces cosas distintas en el?  Es que no cambian mis comentarios de antes si es lo mismo, es decir, si llamas a los estilos mediante un <link> no podras usar el $_POST ni recuperarlo de ninguna parte, ni el $_SESSION, ni nada, son peticiones nuevas inconexas (para que estuvieran conectadas con esas variables tendrias que usar include o require, pero no mediante una nueva llamada <link> en html)

Comment: Pero la solución casi que la tienes, porque dices que lo sacas de una base de datos, pues nada, coges y en el main.php que te genera el CSS haces la consulta y lo rellenas con su resultado, y yasta.

Comment: Te recomendaría que actualizases la redirección `main.php` como si fuera un `.css` real con `.htaccess`. Así: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule style.css main.php [L]`

Comment: Asi es. Yo hago la busqueda en el mismo archivo css y nada 
$sql_estilos_usar = "SELECT * FROM estilos";
if ($res_estilos_usar = mysqli_query($link,$sql_estilos_usar))
    { if (mysqli_num_rows($res_estilos_usar) > 0) {  while ($row_usar = mysqli_fetch_array($res_estilos_usar)) { 
$quecolor=$row_usar['color_linea_menu'];
if($quecolor=="")
   { $quecolor="red"; } 
   else
  { $quecolor=$row_usar['color_linea_menu']; }    
}} }

 Por lo que me decis, es como que al llamar al archivo por <link> este no tiene conexion seguramente Puede ser eso ?

Comment: Bueno, se supone que para que te funcionen las consultas debes hacer un include de la conexion a la base de datos que tengas, o definirla tambien dentro del main.php, pues ahora mismo no la veo en lo que has puesto, y entonces te funcionaria la consulta.

Comment: Perfecto, justo volvia para decir que si, ahora si funciona haciendo la conexion ahí tambien. Yo creia que al hacerla en el index ya todo cargar sobre el mismo ya la tenia ejecuta
Muchisimas gracias por aclararme todo. Son de gran ayuda

Comment: Me alegro que ya te funcione bien :-)  Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que esta en que la línea de incluir el archivos css solo hace una referencia. Mirar [esta discusión](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1445424/1545868) (en inglés).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.php" />
```

La cuestión está en cómo el HTML le pasa las variables a esa referencia, y si es que se las pasa.

La forma más sencilla de arreglarlo, es obligar a **php** a traer el **css** a nuestro archivo principal, cambiando la línea en cuestión por esta otra:

```
<style><?php include 'main.php';?></style>
```

Si optas por esa solución, eliminar la línea del `header('Content-type: text/css');`